# How to interchange 2 vertex position ? I want vertex A to be at vertex B position and vertex B to be at vertex A position

Tags: vertices, faces

I need that because I face this situation :

[image]

[image]

I want the small area between these two overlapping faces to be a hole.

Answer (score 3):

If you need vertices to be swithced places you can scale them by -1. Select them and hit  <kbd>s</kbd> followed by <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I must do something wrong. It does nothing. But I solved my problem by doing something else.